# string in correct json format but im still getting error while converting

Tags: java, android-studio

im trying to convert data from json array to json object but I'm getting an error and I don't know why
java code here

```
void addToList(String json)
{
    try
    {
        ja = new JSONArray(json);

        for(int i = 0;i<ja.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject item = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            String sent  = item.getString("#")+" x "+item.getString("name");
            items.add(sent);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
        itemlist.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

json = ["{"name":"fish","#":"1"}"]
and the error I'm getting is

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"name":"fish","#":"1"} at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: Your ` ["{"name":"fish","#":"1"}"]` is invalid. It should be [
  {
    "name": "fish",
    "#": "1"
  }
]

Answer (score 1):

This is the constructor of a JSONObject:

```
Parameters:
    source - `A string beginning with { (left brace) and ending with } (right brace).` 
Throws:
    JSONException - If there is a syntax error in the source string or a duplicated key.
```

That means in your case specifically that json can't be an array. Try using something like:

```
json = "{"name":"fish","#":"1"}"
```